# What do "NAC Dynamic" and "ASFT" mean according to the image in the LTAF AIP document?

Tags: airport, braking, aeronautical-information

What do "NAC Dynamic" and "ASFT" mean according to the image in the LTAF AIP document? I found out that ASFT stands for "Airport Surface Friction Tester" but I don't know what "NAC Dynamic" is and I don't know what "NAC" stands for. If it is an acronym and you know what it stands for, the acronym for "NAC" is important.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NAC Dynamic ("Friction Tester")](https://www.aviationpros.com/aoa/runway-management/product/10656965/neubert-aero-corp-nacdynamic-friction-tester) is a "...continuous friction measurement device...".

**NAC** stands for [Neubert Aero Corp.](https://www.aviationpros.com/airports/airport-technology/company/10132196/neubert-aero-corp)

([ASFT](https://www.airport-technology.com/contractors/apron_clean/asft-swiss/)) is an Airport Surface Friction Tester.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.